# jQuery Layout Plugin + AngularJS Tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-plugins, jquery-layout

I use [jQuery layout plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/). Inside a pane I use tabs created by angularjs (code below). When I close the layout pane (south pane in the jsfiddle) and open it again, the tabs don't work anymore. Resizing doesn't cause this problem.

```
directive('tabs', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            var tabpanes = $scope.tabpanes = [];

            $scope.select = function (tabpane) {
                angular.forEach(tabpanes, function (tabpane) {
                    tabpane.selected = false;
                });
                tabpane.selected = true;
            }

    this.addTabPane = function (tabpane) {
                if (tabpanes.length == 0) $scope.select(tabpane);
                tabpanes.push(tabpane);
            }
  },
        template:
        '<div class="tabbable">' +
        '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
        '<li ng-repeat="tabpane in tabpanes" ng-class="{active:tabpane.selected}">' +
        '<a href="" ng-click="select(tabpane)">{{tabpane.title}}</a>' +
        '</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>',
        replace: true
    };
}).
directive('tabpane', function () {
    return {
        require: '^tabs',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { title: '@' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
            tabsCtrl.addTabPane(scope);
        },
        template:
        '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
        '</div>',
        replace: true
    };
})
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfn5z/84/

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle that shows the error?

Comment: I try to get it run in jsfiddle without success: http://jsfiddle.net/jfn5z/84/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not you use [angular-ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or [angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)

Or please make jsfiddle or pluncker .

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

Working  ==>    `fiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/Nishchit14/jfn5z/85/

Comment: this does not work. Close the south pane and open it again => tabs don't work anymore

Comment: First of all sorry for my miss understanding , it seems like layout plugin changes 'active' class on ( .tab-content.pane-tab).  Please check this if it will help [tab] (http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/tab)